# Does this code contain undefined behavior or a hidden bug? Something I missed?

Tags: c, ansi-c

This is a piece of code testing a function titled 'logf', which takes two arguments and uses them to log a bit of information. In this case, the first argument to the function is the string to be logged, and the second argument is a string holding a path in a filesystem to a log file. The first string is printed, with a timestamp, to stdout and the log file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1

typedef struct tm tm;

int logf(char input_string[], char log_file_string[])
{
    /*Initializations.*/
    char output_string[32767];
    FILE* log_file_stream;
    time_t current_time_epoch_format;
    tm* current_time_calandar_format;

    /*Creating timestamp in output string, amending first argument to output string, and logging.*/
    if ((strlen(input_string) + 23) > 32767) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((current_time_epoch_format = time(&current_time_epoch_format)) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((current_time_calandar_format = localtime(&current_time_epoch_format)) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (strftime(output_string, 23, "[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S] ", current_time_calandar_format) != 22) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((log_file_stream = fopen(log_file_string, "a")) == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string)) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (fprintf(log_file_stream, "%s\n", output_string) < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (fclose(log_file_stream) == EOF) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*Initializations.*/
    int EXIT_CODE;

    /*Print the returned integer from logf and exit.*/
    printf("%d\n", (EXIT_CODE = logf(argv[1], argv[2])));
    exit(EXIT_CODE);
}
```

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: 32k array - what is the target? On an embedded system this could be a problem. Note that the array need only be 23 bytes long as its use in `printf("%s\n", strcat(output_string, input_string))` is unnecessary (just use `printf("%s\n", input_string)`)

Comment: @William Morris: What about the timestamp? Should printf("%s%s\n", output_string, input_string) be used?

Comment: Note that your code leaks an open file if there's a problem after the file is opened in `logf()` but before it is closed.  That's avoidable, and best avoided.  EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS are defined in `<stdlib.h>`; redefining them is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

This program invokes undefined behavior because the name `logf` is reserved for external use. It's the name of one of the standard math functions. Whether it also invoked undefined behavior for other reasons I haven't inspected.